# Can I use percentage units with CSS3 matrix transform

Tags: css, matrix, css-transforms

I'm not sure if I set up position of some elements wrong or I simply can't use "%" for `matrix` transform. I'm trying to do something like this -->

```
element.style.transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,-100%)"
```

But that does nothing.

Comment: No, you can't use percentages in a matrix... Add another transform if you want to do this.

Comment: no, it could. @vals you can. but all of em should be percentage

Comment: No, @vals is correct. You can't use a percentage inside the `matrix` function as the specs itself doesn't mention percentage as a valid value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Can we use percentage inside matrix function?

No, you can't use percentage values inside a `matrix` transform function. Below is an extract from the [W3C Specs for Transform Functions](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms/#two-d-transform-functions). As you can see there, the parameters for the `matrix` function are specified as just `<number>` whereas for the `translate` functions it is `<number-percentage>`. This shows that the matrix can accept only numeric values whereas the translate can accept percentage.

> **matrix() = matrix( <number> [, <number> ]{5,5} )**
>
> specifies a 2D transformation in the form of a transformation matrix of the six values a-f.
>
> **translate() = translate( <length-percentage> [, <length-percentage> ]? )**
>
> specifies a 2D translation by the vector [tx, ty], where tx is the first translation-value parameter and ty is the optional second translation-value parameter. If <ty> is not provided, ty has zero as a value.
>
> **translateX() = translateX( <length-percentage> )**
>
> specifies a translation by the given amount in the X direction.
>
> **translateY() = translateY( <length-percentage> )**
>
> specifies a translation by the given amount in the Y direction.
>
> **matrix3d() = matrix3d( <number> [, <number> ]{15,15} )**
>
> specifies a 3D transformation as a 4x4 homogeneous matrix of 16 values in column-major order.
>
> **translate3d() = translate3d( <length-percentage> , <length-percentage> , <length> )**
>
> specifies a 3D translation by the vector [tx,ty,tz], with tx, ty and tz being the first, second and third translation-value parameters respectively.

---

### How does the spec define a number value?

And the below is how the [W3C Spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#number-value) defines the `<number>`:

> **Number values** are denoted by <number>, and **represent real numbers, possibly with a fractional component**.
>
> When written literally, a number is either an integer, or zero or more decimal digits followed by a dot (.) followed by one or more decimal digits and optionally an exponent composed of "e" or "E" and an integer. It corresponds to the <number-token> production in the CSS Syntax Module [CSS3SYN]. As with integers, the first character of a number may be immediately preceded by - or + to indicate the number’s sign.

---

### So what should I do now?

You should convert the percentage value into a normal real number and then use it inside the `matrix` function. It is generally the dimension of the box in the required axis (including borders and padding) * the required percentage. So, for a box with 100x100px dimension, 5px padding and a 1px border on all sides), 100% translate would be equal to 112 whereas -50% would be equal to -56.

You can refer to [The Matrix Resolutions](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/matrix/) site to see it in action. Below is a demo with both approaches.

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rebeccapurple;
  background: rgba(102, 51, 153, 0.25);
}
.translate {
  transform: translate(100%, 100%);
}
.matrix {
  transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 112, 112);
}
```

```html
<div class='matrix'>Hello! I'm using matrix.</div>
<div class='translate'>Hello! I'm using translate.</div>
```